# Cannot create user because the group does not exits on ansible

Tags: mysql, ansible

I am running this playbook to install mysql.

File *var.yml*:

```yaml
PORT : 3306
USER : mysql
USERID : "{{ PORT }}"
GROUP : mysql
GROUPID : "{{ PORT }}"
SECGROUP : wls
DBUSER : root
DBPASSWD : "{{ DBPASS }}"

GROUPS:
  - name: "{{ GROUP }}"
    gid: "{{ GROUPID }}"

USERS:
  - name : "{{ USER }}"
    uid: "{{ USERID }}"
    group: "{{ GROUP }}"
    groups: "{{ SECGROUP }}"
    comment: "{{ USER }}"
```

*playbook.yml*:

```yaml
tasks:
 - name: 1. create group
   group:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    gid: "{{ item.gid }}"
    state: present
   with_items:
     - "{{ GROUPS }}"

 - name: 2. create user account
   user:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    group: "{{ item.group }}"
    groups: "{{ item.groups }}"
    uid: "{{ item.uid }}"
    comment: "{{ item.comment }}"
   with_items:
     - "{{ USERS }}"
```

When I run it, I have an issue with the second task:

> failed : (item={u'comment': u'mysql', u'group': u'mysql', u'name': u'mysql', u'groups': u'wls', u'uid': u'3306'}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": {"comment}: "mysql", "group": "mysql", "groups" : "wls", "name": "mysql", "uid": "3306"}, "msg": "Group wls does not exist"}

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

It's because group `wls` does not exist as error says: `"msg": "Group wls does not exist"`

You cannot create an user with a non-existent group in its `groups`. You either need to remove group `wls` from `USERS[0].groups` or create group `wls`. Your task 1. only creates group `mysql`.

To create both groups in task 1. You can just add group `wls` to the list:

```
GROUPS:
  - name: "{{ GROUP }}"
    gid: "{{ GROUPID }}"
  - name: "{{ SECGROUP }}"
    gid: "<provide gid here>"
```

(Note: normally in Ansible you don't have to provide `gid` to `group` action and it would chose one, but the way you have written your task 1 requires it).

This will make your task 1 create both `mysql` and `wls` groups and also pass task 2.

Comment: how can I create group wls in task 1?

Comment: @KevinTran I updated my answer, you just need to add it to list of items task 1 runs with.

Comment: I am trying to do it, thank you for your information.

Comment: @blami: when you create groups which will mainly be used by system processes on a large number of machines, it is a rather good idea to provide a stable group id. Same goes for users. This makes it for example much easier to reinstall a machine from scratch and restore a backup without having to remember the old gid/uid and chown all files/directories in a hurry. Moreover, it is very easy to make the gid/uid optional in the above tasks by using e.g. [`gid: "{{ item.gid | default(omit) }}"`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#making-variables-optional)